# Installed Flask, but get "ImportError: No module named flask". What could be the reason?

Tags: python, pip

At empty CentOS I do this (following tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7):

```
  sudo yum install python-pip python-devel gcc nginx
  sudo pip install virtualenv
  mkdir ~/myproject
  cd ~/myproject
  virtualenv myprojectenv
  source myprojectenv/bin/activate
  pip install gunicorn flask
  pip list
  pip show flask
  nano ~/myproject/myproject.py
  python myproject.py
```

Then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myproject.py", line 1, in <module>
  from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

What could be them problem with it?

Comment: most common is your programm runs on python 3.X but pip install on python 2.X
run `pip3 install flask` and retry

Comment: That helped, thank you!